# How to forbid the use of the default constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, object, constructor

I don't want to make it possible in my program to create an object without passing arguments to the constructor.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 39):

While the other answers are true, there is a new technique in C++11 for expressing that : [deleted default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor)

It allows forbidding a function without depending on any other trick. It also clearly express your intention in the code.

```
class X
{ 
public:
    X(int) {}
    X() = delete; // will never be generated
};

int main()
{ 
    X x; // will not compile;
    X y(1); // will compile.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But `X x();` will compile.

Comment: @Ingo, that is because of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse .  In short, what is happening there is that you are declaring a function `x` that takes no arguments and returns a type `X`.

Answer (score 34):

When you declare any other constructor, the compiler will not generate the default constructor for you. If you have specified a default no-argument constructor, you can make it private.

Remember that the compiler can automatically generate each of these 4 member functions for a class.

- default no argument constructor
- default destructor
- copy constructor
- assignment operator

But it will not generate a default one if you have declared one yourself, i.e., if you declared a constructor yourself, it will not create the default constructor. If you didn't declare any of the other 3 though, the compiler can generate them.

edit: Note that this information applies to C++03, but it is different in C++11 as Matthieu M. mentions in the comments. C++11 also allows for the constructor to be explicitly forbidden. See [Offirmo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8078146/9614249).

Comment: Note: the rule change a bit for C++11, declaring a move constructor or move assignment operator will automaticaly prevent the automatic creation of a copy constructor and copy assignment operator. It's sensible, but a different spirit.

Comment: @MatthieuM. - thanks for pointing that out. I'm still writing from a C++03 perspective, but I should mention that.

Comment: I'm not sure you got the rule right about when the compiler may generate a constructor.  The rule for the default constructor is that *any* user defined constructor inhibits its automatic generation.  The rule for the other three is that a user defined version of that particular operation inhibits its automatic generation.  Independently of what the user may have done for the others; if you define a default constructor, or a destructor, you still get an automatic copy constructor.

Comment: @James - I clarified what I meant - I meant what you said, not what I wrote, which on second reading did imply that the compiler would not generate any of the default functions if any of them were specified.

Answer (score 10):

Define a constructor taking the correct argument(s). This will prevent the compiler from defining a default constructor.

```
class X { 
public:
   X(int) {}
};

int main(){ 
    X x; // will not compile;
    X y(1); // will compile.
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you can create an object without passing arguments to the constructor is that you have a default constructor. A default constructor  is a kind of constructor which doesn't have a parameter or all parameters having  default values. And if you didn't declare any constructor, the compiler will make one for you.
So, the solution is very easy. You can declare a constructor with a parameter without default value, then the compiler won't bother to make the constructor to you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a private default constructor.

Comment: That's still accessible by members and friends of the class. It's better to just define constructors taking arguments, which will remove the implicit default constructor completely.

Answer (score 1):

creating a non empty constructor "cancels" the empty default constructor, so if you don't explicitly also create an empty constructor, no objects will be created without giving arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just declare constructor, but not define it.

```
class MyClass
{
   MyClass();
}
```

Comment: You can do

public: MyClass() = delete;


The intention is clearer and gives you better compiler error in case someone tried to use the default constructor.

Comment: I have heard that deleting a constructor is a bad practice and it is better to leave it undefined.

Comment: could you cite the link to it?