# In the UML class diagram, what is the best way to show that the default constructor is disabled?

Tags: constructor, uml

I have a quick question. When we draw the UML class diagram, what is the best way to denote that the default constructor is disabled? In C++, we may have classes designed in this way.

One way might be just making the Constructor method with "-" sign. But I heard that in UML class diagram, we usually do not include constructors and destructors. So I wonder what is the usual way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068088/how-to-forbid-the-use-of-the-default-constructor-in-c) you can mark it as private. So prefixing with `-` is fine.

There is no rule as to which you show the constructor in your operations compartment. Just show it with the private mark.