# Can't figure out how or why this code solves an error. ESP32 arduino IDE with platform dot io

Tags: arduino, esp32, platformio

I am fairly new to coding and especially to C++ but usually with enough googling and breaking problems down to simpler blocks I can figure things out. This issue makes no sense to me though and the solution I just happened to come up with on accident makes even less sense to me.

I am writing a program for ESP32-S in vscode with platformio and broke this down to isolate what was causing the error and found this issue with class/object declaration:

This code will compile but I get a link error twice that says

> undefined reference to `point::point()'

```
#include <Arduino.h>
class point {
  public:
    point();
    point(uint day){
      this->_day = day;
    }
    uint _day;
};
class channel {
  public:
    channel(String _color, byte _pin){
    }
    point _points[64];
};
channel red("red", 0);
void setup() {}
void loop() {}
```

Meanwhile this code with one seemingly unrelated change compiles and links without issue:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
class point {
  public:
    point();
    point(uint day){
      this->_day = day;
    }
    uint _day;
};
class channel {
  public:
    channel(){ // <--- Removing the arguments from channel constructor fixes it?
    }
    point _points[64];
};
channel red(); // <--- And here of course
void setup() {}
void loop() {}
```

I don't know why that fixes it, and I have a workaround for now if this is what I have to do, but I want to understand. Thanks.

Comment: I'm also not sure why it doesn't produce the error but the correct fix is to define the constructor for `point` that takes no arguments. You declared one with `point()` but there's no definition (hence the `point::point()` error).

Comment: Point needs to have arguments, though. Is it really not possible to do this at all in C++?

Comment: If you declare the form of the constructor without arguments - which you did - you must define it.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared a constructor `point::point()`, but not defined it (i.e. it has no body). This is not OK with the linker and that's what you're being told.

There are three ways to fix this.

1. Don't declare the constructor (compiler generates a default constructor which may or may not initialize the member `_day` to 0, depending on compiler and platform). Note that you also have the interesting alternative of [deleting the default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068088/how-to-forbid-the-use-of-the-default-constructor-in-c).
2. Declare and define it to do whatever you consider appropriate.
3. Give your constructor `point::point(uint day)` a default argument value, e.g.: `point::point(uint day = 0)`.

Side note on C style arrays of C++ objects like here:

```
point _points[64];
```

This is a dangerous combination, unless you know exactly what you're doing. See the [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/containers#arrays-are-evil)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand what went wrong now and just removed arguments from that class and am setting those values separately.